# Redirect non-www to www giving me hundreds of 404's

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks to anyone who can take a moment to look at this.

Recently I created a new section "subdomain" in my website and in this new folder I have  includes a Joomla CMS installation the url looks like this: http://www.example.com/subdomain/

In this folder I have a htaccess file to which I have added.

```
## No directory listings
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I try to access say http://example.com/subdomain/anytrailingstring then it's NOT redirecting me to http://www.example.com/subdomain/anytrailingstring as I expected, it is redirecting to http://www.example.com/anytrailingstring leaving out the /subdomain/ and this is of course a page that doesnt exist and therefore a 404.

This is a problem.

I do not have any directive in the root .htacces file except for this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can someone perhaps see why the subdomain htaccess isnt redirecting to correctly? Did I miss something?

I am not good with htaccess at all, if anybody can help me I would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of the backreference (`$1`). The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) is relative to the current directory, so excludes the parent subdirectory (ie. `/subdomain` in your example).

Do it like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache since the erroneous (301 - permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

However, a couple of questions:

- Why are you not using HTTPS? (You are redirecting to HTTPS in the parent `.htaccess` file - but this is now being overridden by the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory.)
- Why not include this in the parent `.htaccess` file?

**UPDATE:** So, taking the above points into consideration... if you want to move this rule to the parent `.htaccess` file in the root then have it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect non-www to www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The order of the directives is to ensure there is only ever at most 1 redirect (assuming you are not implementing HSTS).

You were unnecessarily duplicating the `RewriteEngine` directive (so I removed the second instance).

The `RewriteBase` directive was not being used.

The capturing subgroup in your HTTP to HTTPS rule was not required. ie. `^` is better than `^(.*)$` in this instance.

---

*Aside:.*

> ...a new section "subdomain" in my website and in this new folder I have includes a Joomla CMS installation the url looks like this: `http://www.example.com/subdomain/`

This is a *subdirectory*, not a "subdomain".

This is a "subdomain":

```
http://subdomain.example.com/
```

Comment: I agree as to subdirectory and yes, you are right, thats should be https.  It was picked up from a  post from 12 years ago.  Question: This I should now put in the subfolder or in the root htaccess file? I guess you imply it  probably should be in the root. Right?

Comment: "This I should now put in the subfolder or in the root htaccess file?" - Well, I wondered if you had a specific requirement for why this should be the subdirectory? However, ordinarily this should be in the root `.htaccess` file since you normally want to enforce www on the entire site. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.  For some reason it doesnt do anything in the root htacess but I added it to the folder and it works fine!  Have a great Sunday

Comment: "it doesnt do anything in the root htacess" - Do you have other directives in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file? If so, then the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file might be getting overridden (and one reason why you might include the directives in the subdirectory instead). Otherwise, they really should work in the root directory.